# Why during drag a control from toolbox to web form the Visual Studio 2013 add style to this control automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stylesheet, visual-studio-2013

When drag a control from **ToolBox** to **WebForm**, visual studio 2013  add style automatically to this control like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
style="z-index: 1; left: 1129px; top: 540px; position: absolute" Text="Button" />
```

But I will not the visual studio add style to control automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual studio go to **Tools|Options**

go to **HTML Designer|CSS Styling** then:

1. select **Manual Style Application**
2. uncheck **Change positioning to absolute added using ToolBox, paste or drag and drop**.

[image]